# linear space and subspaces - dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$ is linear space, $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of $X$, such that $\dim(U)=\dim(V)=5$.  Then
a. $\dim(X)=8\Rightarrow dim(U\cap V) \le 2$
It is not true. It is possible that $U=V$, then $\dim(U\cap V)=5$.  It is possible still that $\dim(X)=8$.  For example $X=\mathbb{R}^8$, $U=V=span([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0])$

b.  $\dim(U\cap V) =0 \Rightarrow \dim(X)=10$
It is fairly obvious. However, I am not sure about it.

c. $\dim(U+V)=\dim(X)\Rightarrow \dim(X)\le 10$
It is true, 
$$\dim(X)=\dim(U+V) + \dim(U\cap V) = \dim(U)+\dim(V) $$
$$\dim(X)=\dim(U+V) = 10 -\dim(U\cap V)\le 10$$

Am I ok in a. and c. ? Could you help me with b. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The b. is not necessarily true, take as example $X=\mathbb R^{11}$, if we set $U=span\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5\}$, and $V=span\{e_6,e_7,e_8,e_9,e_{10}\}$, then $dim(U\cap V)=0$, but $dim(X)\neq 10$.

Comment: What about a. and c. ? Is it ok ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, in c. there is only one little problem, $dim(X)\neq dim(U+V)+dim(U\cap V)$, but the equation under this one is correct, and then follows the result.